# How can I get value of multiple Select tag with the same name in Servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets, dynamic, html-select

This approach works perfectly for text inputs but it does not work with selects!

Is there any way to get Select values like an array; except than using hidden values or javascript?

String[] levelDropdowns = request.getParameterValues("levelDropdown");

```html
<select name="levelDropdown">
  <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">Select ...</option>
  <option value="level1">level 1</option>
  <option value="level2">level 2</option>
</select>

<select name="levelDropdown">
  <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">Select ...</option>
  <option value="level1">level 1</option>
  <option value="level2">level 2</option>
</select>
```

I want to have access to levelDeopdowns[0] and levelDeopdowns[1] in my java code!

Answer (score 0):

Add the `multiple` attribute to you select tag:

```
<select name="levelDropdown" multiple>
```

And now, with just one select tag you can select multiple values.

Comment: I don't want multiple value of on select! I need values of multiple selects in the same variable in my java code.

Comment: @kavehmb, If that's what you're looking for, why not just use `request.getParameterMap()` to get a map of all parameters? And of course name the selects differently.